# Regular Expression starts with "AB" or "EX" and only uses alphanumeric values

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core

This is what I've come up with so far but it doesn't seem to work

```
    [RegularExpression("/^(AB|EX)?([a-z0-9])/i")]
```

I understand that ^(AB/EX) means start with and the /i is for case invariant.
How can I add in the alphanumeric characters for the rest of the string?

Comment: I think you need `[RegularExpression("([Aa][Bb]|[Ee][Xx])[a-zA-Z0-9]*")]`. `AB` or `EX` are obligatory, aren't they? Otherwise, `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` would suffice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Probably should have a `$` anchor at the end to make sure it isn't followed by non-alphanumerics.

Comment: @juharr Actually, the `RegularExpressionAttribute` regex should match the whole input, so even `^` is redundant. I removed it from the comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works. Thanks!

Comment: @user2806570 Great, I posted the answer with explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use regex delimiters with `RegularExpressionAttribute` regex patterns. Also, you cannot pass any options since the client-side validation is performed with JS and its RegExp engine does not support any inline modifiers.

Also, bear in mind the pattern here will be used to match the entire input, so `^` and `$` anchors are redundant.

Use

```
[RegularExpression("([Aa][Bb]|[Ee][Xx])[a-zA-Z0-9]*")]
```

It will be match a string that fully matches:

- `([Aa][Bb]|[Ee][Xx])` - `Ab` / `aB` / `ab` / `AB` or `EX` (also in a case insensitive way)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ ASCII alphanumeric chars to the end of the string.